# How to convert an in-line image to a floating image in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, png, image-editing

I would like images that I insert into Word documents to have *white* resize handles and for it to be possible to group them with other images:

[image]

Currently, when I insert an image into a Word document, it has *grey* resize handles and there is no option to group it with other images:

[image]

How can I modify images that currently have *grey* resize handles so that they have *white* resize handles and allow me to group them with other images?

Comment: I've tried to replicate your issue, but couldn't (inserting / copying png / jpeg / gif / bmp all have white corners in Word 365). How exactly you insert the picture (through insert tab, or just copy paste?), does it change if you use different method? What is the file type of the images you insert? Can you spot any difference between pictures with white / grey corners? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why are there two types of image-resize handles here?

This slightly confusing problem can be best explained by looking at how image handles appear in four specific scenarios:

**Word 2003 and earlier:**

1. Image wrapping style = `In Line With Text`:

[image]

2. Image wrapping style = **not** `In Line With Text`:

[image]

**Word 2007 and later:**

3. Image wrapping style = `In Line With Text`:

[image]

4. Image wrapping style = **not** `In Line With Text`:

[image]

> How can I modify images that currently have *grey* resize handles so that they have *white* resize handles and allow me to group them with other images?

The grey resize handles indicate that you are using an older version of Word (2003 or earlier) and that your image is configured to appear in line with text.

## Solution:

1. Double click on any in-line image that has gray resize handles.
2. From the `Layout` tab, choose any option *other than* `In line with text`.

Your in-line image has now been converted to a floating image, has white resize handles, and you are now able to group it with other floating images.

Comment: I am using MS Word 2016. Also what you meant in the solution step 2 is found in Wrap Text. Is that what you meant? I am still not getting the required resize handle.

Comment: @KiranCNayak There's a subtle difference between the handles in 2003 and 2007 that I missed: there are *only* round handles in 2003 but mixed round and circular handles in 2007+. I'll update my answer in a moment. Next question: is this a .doc or .docx file? I'm guessing it's just a .doc?

Comment: No I checked, it is a .docx file

Comment: How are you inserting the image? Pasting it from the clipboard or via the `Insert` menu? Does it make any difference which method you use?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Word for Office 365 (16.0.12527.20986) 64-bit and the above solution works for me as follows:

1. Change layout to anything other than 'in line with text'
2. Click outside the image
3. Change layout back to 'inline with text'

Then the useful handles reappear